# How to create a closable tabbed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, viewmodel

I was watching this David's article. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2011/01/23/closable-tabbed-views-in-prism.aspx

He's using blend interacvity. I want to do the same thing but using commands and also using PRISM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only David's example. I'm trying to do this in WPF, maybe I'm wrong, but I couldn't do it because I wasn't be able to import interactivity library

Comment: @DarfZon The interactivity library ships with [Expressions Blend's SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10801) and is not included in .NET 4

Comment: @Lester well, I asked because, some of my views, can't close. So, I prefer to this using commands..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](http://blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/15/WPF-TabControl-series-Part-4-Closeable-TabItems.aspx) si what you are looking for.... instead of code behind you can modify things for MVVM. Its a nice article... check the other parts as well for more info